# how to insert background images in nuxt generate

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm sorry if it's obvious

I'm creating several thousand pages using nuxt generate like this

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="main-picture">
           <span>{{landing.name}}<span>
        </div>
    </div>
<template>
```

```
<script>
import { landingshs } from '~/db/landingshs'
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            link: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4d/Cat_November_2010-1a.jpg"
        }
    },
    asyncData({ params }) {
    const landing = landingshs.find(l => l.id === params.id)
    
    return {landing}

 },

</script>
```

now I'm trying to set a picture like this

```
<style>
.main-picture {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
    background-image: v-bind("`url(${link})`");
}
</style>
```

I also tried to do it this way but without success.
With this approach, there is not even a request in the network

```
 mounted() {
  setTimeout(() =>{
    document.querySelector('.main-picture').style.backgroundImage = "url(" + this.link + ")";
      }, 5000);
     
    },
```

When creating a regular page (not _id.vue) everything works fine

nuxt generate itself works well, inserts the necessary data

Nuxt@2.15.8
Vue@2.7.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you try to use that way

```
 background-image: url({{link}});
```

if it's not working try this on template

```
:style="{ backgroundImage: `url(${link})` }"
```